# How to add a new prerequisites in InstallShield Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, setup-project, software-distribution, prerequisites, installshield-le

I am building a setup project for windows desktop application using Visual Studio 2013 and Instal Shield 2015 Limted Edition.

This application has two dependent run time environment

1. SQL Server 2012 LocalDB
2. Adobe Flash Player ActiveX

The option 1 is already listed in the installshield Redistributable and i am able to include but i couldn't find any redistributable item for option 2.

My setup project need to check the Adobe Flash Player ActiveX status in the machine, if not found then it has to install it automatically before installing the actual application.

Any Merge module available for Adobe Flash Player ActiveX?

How to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed professional edition of installshield software(trial) 
[src](https://esdhttp.flexnetoperations.com/cgi-bin/download?rid=3988578407&rp=DTM20160407110851MzI4Mzg3MTc4) .

Followed the tutorial  [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShnXGqLycY) to create a new Adobe ActiveX.prq file

Included the same in my setup project and my setup able to detect the Adobe ActiveX status and act as required.

XML Code of my Adobe ActiveX PreRequisite File(open .prq file in Visual Studio to see the same)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SetupPrereq>
    <conditions>
        <condition Type="1" Comparison="2" Path="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayerActiveX" FileName="" ReturnValue=""></condition>
    </conditions>
    <files>
        <file LocalFile="&lt;ProgramFilesFolder&gt;\InstallShield\2015LE\SetupPrerequisites\Adobe ActiveX\flashplayer_21_ax_debug.exe" URL="https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/21/flashplayer_21_ax_debug.exe" CheckSum="F60EDF21DC3F89980651BE01FFB22F9F" FileSize="0,19762368"></file>
    </files>
    <execute file="flashplayer_21_ax_debug.exe"></execute>
    <properties Id="{72D7E3D1-C9DF-4FA6-9F9B-4E5117AB2920}" Description="This prerequisite installs the Adobe ActiveX V21." AltPrqURL=""></properties>
</SetupPrereq>
```

This code will help someone in need.